# How to reduce apk bloat through library usage?

Tags: android, jar

I added google-collect-1.0.jar to my Android project and it made a 50K .apk into a 250k .apk (both Release).

This was all through using a single method Lists.newArrayList()

Is there any way to reduce the overhead?

Comment: Strip the jar of what you dont need and recompile (if its legally allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only using a single method, which from looking at the source amounts to this:

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList() {
    return new ArrayList<E>();
}
```

..then why not just implement that yourself (or at a minimum include only `Lists.java`) in your project?

Comment: It's a fair point. I do intent to use more in the future, I'd rather not have to keep copying over.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK includes a tool called proguard to sort of shrink wrap your release: [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)